# output base64 image in html nodemailer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, base64, nodemailer

I am trying to send out an email with node mailer, and it is sending the email, but I am trying to use an image in there, a base64 image. I've converted the image to base64, and done this:

```
var base64 = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2ODApLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gODIK/9sAQwAGBAQFBAQGBQUFBgYGBwkOCQkICAkSDQ0KDhUSFhYVEhQUFxohHBcYHxkUFB0nHR8iIyUlJRYcKSwoJCshJCUk/9sAQwEGBgYJCAkRCQkRJBgUGCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQk/8AAEQgAtwETAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5+v/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AdaWUxx+8f861boSW2kK4Yq/mY3Z5qzbQKBwKqeJD5Olxn/prRWptQbRtRknUSZy19mRwWOWJJJPemxoBjP1pJ7hVCu/ABxxzzTZr6G3kKSZ3Dk1z4aSVPU7MRH39BurSXM5iZNkWx8qDzvx6+lYWvI9/qsUxBkcoSGRuM44/CtnVLlLnS2mtCrNHySeoHpXLXDvahpYn3O3Own7o9BXj4mm41HyHPKLRBOxCpJJlpz94NyR9Kr28MkqvIkYUZz7itFBCYle6VkkHIBPP/wCqqthchrgo0oKs2MJ/DWHPpp0MZb3L+naoLWeK/wDMNu64IG0jcR9e9dLqd9rcjQatNOAtw3JikAbA9QKx4rOCW6W3uroArEX2su4D0/OtqDTpJdQsrd4HjU4VlKHYM+/0rKcr20KijptL1XU728s4xMpAYE5AwQe/1p2reJ7G68Ri2vI9iRv8wLYBGMZNc3r2u2Gh37aOlvLNJCMKyHZ5fod3U1R1OLQtd0S+uBPcx6pBCZFl3EjjsalZbPl5+V8r6j543tfU0fF2rJYDf4f1GZ4WYhkU5VR6Vwdz4vuJJiZHODxtYnml0K7t2tE+338gyB8mPve1SeJpNMm0DGmWp+1xMDuAzkGvawdKpQVkRu22wsvFQeRYponUMe/AFX7SeO7kQ2sYkmDHahXK/lXI6XbSyJb/AGhW3kfMGrpdOtxb3kgjJUqgbg9ORW1am6r5mUtCaWPU0uriOa3ZpZB95eMY6celUHuLq9uF+z2+9kJLn+9jvXqHhfS4L2eymljEjsSCW59a8/1aeKz1jVbJ4x887ojdAnPTiuWWDnCPMVz3djOvQbiEu1wgCAFo1Y5OT0+tSxW+mWyNI7iRkX5k3lWOR0we4qeW1Eej2ciqd01yybxHw3pzSz2BvnazPlQzW7lWlk7/AF9axdOUVe2jDRvQqGZLW4hEMMtsy/OA7Esy96gvtXOo263DqFt0O0KoALEdyPf1rSt9StrG2+yX1t9th+Zo3OVIbGCVNUtui6o5toRJZOWURBz8r+rE9vpUqCa0A6PwvqGjGKODVbSNNkbvHLGc7mIyuR7GrfijV7XXvCsAFnGNRicI00S7MxAHgj0zXJ291pthe3cbuwMMbIpB3IzdiKpf2ldXrMyyhgyhfLj7j2zQqUlZlxbOl8I+Jk0iObSpmYRXq7WBkK+U/VXH0NMfUvPhnhmnknilZncnGXZT1BrHk0W6ufnn2LkDbg8r+NLb6OY54YXMjIDuZscfQHtVxTvpuU6Ul0HHQZxEmqWMsHkIMHy3/eLk4G4ev0rrdG8T6poVnFLYXtxLD5/z74/ljHc5689MVi2unm2aRrRVIY9JeQPwq2I706dLYSNEYXkErEDDEjoPpXVLBVZPmSMedJ2Z7BYay3iiMQ3ulLd2DncrjhtuPvY61g/El7fS/C89x9iubWaLP2R49zh8dj6ZHrXlnh74gTwaokFteXEbxRsspB+VFB5wM16R4j8YzWngOe+i1uG7up1+zG3ZRlC54ZR9OorjipRqJNamvOrHjH/CfanI4jCSZJwMmi48ZarbxmSRWCjr81crp8NydbiV3ynm9N1df4h09U0yVgACMV7sVKSb0Oa7va5mt4/vTxtY/wDAv/rVBJ47vW/hb/vqsd7fHIqNoMJnBzUczvsW723Nr/hK9RbkZwfeioo7X5F4HQUVpyy7GfMfUlqquoZWDD1FZvjOPboyHv5wrV0y2it7aNIUCRgcAVm+N1J0IdciYV01vgZNB2mjz+6SSZYoYY2kkklVQqjJzmuy1HTfCPhswHxHBdXl3Om4xwOQE9uoqLwpoN7Gf7YS+iD7tkULoGAHdvY10h0zwvqd1HPq3lSXVvwrPNtAz6jNYYXCw5OeeqOjE4iUpcsDAtdc+G4UxxeG73aeuZTz/wCPVOH+GNy+6Tw3eo2fvLKc/wDoVdW3hjwPqEiM0cDSYwoSbH6A1ds/BPg+KUTfZo1MZzlpjj+db+yofynO/abXPL/FngjQp9Lk13wot1IkJ/0m3nO5o1/vD2/OvObWzEd8XWDCFskDqB619aWcfhO3mZY5rJWdCjKZRhgexGea+c/iXoKeDPF8tpbXSS20w862CcnYcnB+nT8q8HM8NGL5qGzKtJL3ius+n3dlfSxCWKdCoQOwySOv4VJb+NVayt7YiW5uEckO/wAowB+tcNqtx513G8gSEkfNg4PXrV6zErSRiKFNvVGaQB5OeMA9a81YS9nuLnb+Ejn1GW8up7qbezyueXOSPam2moLBJKjKT5qbBipdYtpIF83y9ivyNvIH41iRz/6SgJ719jQaeHjEynG07k18wEoCYAUHpVyS387RhslMbOoyR2IrNv5MOMAZNaUdxu05N2AMdqzaTbuaIbo5BWJA7SFOCzDrXR2zRw3c0s7+XEIwC2M856D34rkLbVY7P5yny549TXTW8J8UaA0ttK0A+0GNmPqFB6fiB+dc8KtNQZcE5ysjuNC8ZW2mGyCorIGOHc/zx061iarolv4gl1DU7K6kSeNmne3YBgw6naw9PTFZOi+G2tZ4xd35lCt8qgcV1/hnTRpev3FrbqjQyKr7VU7txPPHcYqJVrtRZ2fV/dvYxTEbjwToohnKn7VJk7evNZcEB083/wBtSe5ZiPJIUjy+f1r0G58XW9q7Wn9iWYS3kYKvk8A5wSKibxvbcltGteev7o11zw1Ga1kjzFUknszzS7sDE6M107QxAuYSjHb+NX9d0yzTR9JuIyqm5hdjhe4PBruG8c2pBH9j2nPB/c1BceM7S5VEk0e0cRjCgw/d+lZLAUV9pFe3l2Zy/gC3gY3sN0I5EW2fy/MAOT7VUjjWOV1iVFAXOAMVsaxq8F6Izb2EVs6NwYo9uR6GstoXhvJAwG10DIfaubFwjClyR1O/BS5qnMOaYhQuPxpyTYixjrULLk8c0qsAhDCvPgmerJqxqaSqyljzxWibckEY4xWZojjbIQOhFXpNXQXAhSOVuCGIjJGfrX02DcY0I8x8/ik3Wdjxa/0W7N/csoUAyt39612jEUsIlPChc/lVfUdM1Rb64f7JeBGlYgiNsYzVvVMQv+9DIQq53AjtXNCnF3YpXWhm6fpKxa7DOtyjgy52gV2viZB/ZUo91/nXGabdJ/blpGpBBccg10njHVlhi+yjG5ufyrWCjGEiHL3kcs8QA68/Wq7KSMDGKZJqAeLIBLbse2KntreSWPc5VAemetcXPFbs35r7Gosfyj6Ciqpu5VO0YwOKKf12HYw9mz6qtXWOCMucfKD0rP8AEkX2/TDHbkO4feO3asWx8WbLeLFq7HaDkt7U9vFMzEn7OcE/dzXJUWYVIOHKtetyoxine5l6L4lOn29zZyHbPFP0/wBkmvQ/D3hnQ9Uh+1XWnQTSOeZGUMTXhfi7Tbu71aTWLRpYBjLQqMhuKyNL+JXjfTohFa3N3FGhxtMWc/mK6oupSpqFRGsUr3R9a2fhbw9bOHi02GNx0ZYwCKtw+GdEUnMLsp4IY5Br5u0744+KiPLmt7jOMByM8/lXq3w413WfGNpK9/qk9nIhwAsPDe+SMfhUyxXKtjT2d9bnptvoWiAAR6fa8dMxivF/2ltESS90CSxRYpUimV1jUD5Mrt/rXU+N9A8UaToLX2h+INVv79ZUAgSNPmUnBwAvpXS+GfCkWreHLC88VWz3GpeVmU3B+ZO+PasKrlVi4wVmTJNa3Pi7WJF02Vprhma727UjcZA9CawLXVria8ilnnIaNsiTv9M11HxOCeJviNrKaS0P2OKRxblAVURLgA885rk9J0u7udXS1aEeYh3Mr9MD1p0o8kLPcrkd00jtfDdzFexsGulYMzZhnJJfPT9e/vRaXNn4dvNVSeyhvTLE8MQbrET0cfhXsvwm8NeHLyaO4v7Ky8/lV844wR6Cu3k+C/hS6kkmZZJC53bgRXLWzL2C16muIoWStufIFxcSysD5DcVcjvlazETgowB4Ir6wHwP8JZ/495j+NPHwM8HH79rIw9N1cn9uxW6ZzKlI+MrxnQckYxnNdj4D1SeLQr6OOE3HlTq5jB7MMZH/AHzX0Tr/AMMfhb4btzPrCw26kEBWclm+ijk14v4p1Pw3FqSHwZYPZadIjQszjDzSLhg3XgYJArqw1aVeLcYNLv0NqMeWauxn9ttbapFDPpk5AIbdH39q9a0YJNo15rdk8trPJBiFZgOHztBzz3NeJ3ev3L3ilotmweXhVABGc5PJya9y8N3mnN4LsHuIwYtRxbLCjEEuzYwD25FFZttcu569K1m2c1dQ289xKWmjkk3EyMCOW7nj1OayNW1HTNKTMsibj0X1r0Pw34b+Hl1HOttbS2rRuqTJI7AgkZGfqOa3bj4U+BZ4xNcafC6dQ7yZH55roq5wsPBQnSal5ngzozlJtvc+f5fFthKVWCP524+bpWlBcQ3yxvbMRhQ0gZePwr1O88HfCHTDm5GmRsO3m8/zqj/aXwk0pt9pG0jLwBAjt/8AWrm/tHF1v4VOX3Gfs1H4pHnGqs2mQbrqIw7hkMRxj1zUaRnVdCF3bguts4QsB/C3r+NdZ4h8a+ELm2e2s/C91fDJKi6lEaD8znFeW6l4gurcXFqYUsobuQfuIJgIQg7HnOa9mlRxFeH7+HKiqVVU5XTuWbu/srFsXF184/5Zx/Mxqo/iW6xssNGL+jz8n8ulX9BXRtKvLS9K6fcJHKsksU0ufMUHJXPoeld74i134eX99Ld2ji1SYK3k26YWM45GOn5V1f2cqSTUG/xM55jOTstDzy18Q+NYUK281tZoecCNM/yNQP4o8WG9W2n1uZnbn93gY/SukudS8IDJh1Cfd2DJxXML/Zf9oSXTaqhBJwPKauyjh6jWzRg6zluaNnqXjaS0NwddZF3lQrHOcd+lKfif4y0tmgu0sdQiXr59sjg/oDUq614eW0SFrt2KsWOIyAaibWfDfOZHP1jNP6tVtb/Il1HfVEsHxG8M6k4OueBtN80f8vFj+4dfcf8A66t3vhPwD49KvpPiefSL0jAg1BcqT6bv/r1z2qS+Hb+JVt5jBIDksIScis42+ktDt+2YkHRxCwx+FH1XmjyzX3FKb3Q/xJ8IPFfhZHnksl1CzxlbizPmKR64HP6VzAkMaBXBUgdD/Ku107xPq3hoRf2Nrs8qH70RUhB+B4rUvPEPh3xVEP8AhJdBCXY/5fLBhG7fUdDXn4jK5LWDudFOrbdHmy6pGowYQaK7/wD4Rj4cP8wuNYQH+ElTiiuT+zanYv2iPpq20fTuB9jgH/bMVow6Hpxxmxt/+/Yrnx4nUcLbsfqas2/iqQDPkAexaun2U+wlJdzo49B0w8Gwtj9YxVhPDej450yz/wC/S/4Vjw+LBxvtwPo+avx+K7MryrZ9BUulLsHP5mlF4e0deRptmP8Atkv+FX4YrO1XbGkMQ9FAArn38Z2kas3knCjJLEAAVyup/E6G9GLb93B/fCfe98kdKqGHbdnoc+IxkKMbyZ6Tcatp9km+e5iQemck/lXO6t8VNA0pTuM8zdljT/E15pqmsSSqztIcH0PJ/GuH1W+Zy+OAa6Hh6cFqeLPNq03amrI5fXrHR5/GGpeItNtbm1inmdlgmkDjJJ3dhwT0HOKht4rYX32sIPPdfL4PUcdqfqRJQrkcnPNW9D8F6vrNnd6hbRItvYp5pmnJVWxztHqeDXhV1KM2j7DDYmlLDqpfTqdR4YXT7jUdHvNM0MpNpc3n3t6vKud4G3k84GeAD34716OfijMCwW1iGDj7xq14dEzeF2hutHSxlgdTNEj7kKsoKuv+yf8AGsLUfCtpdTNLHMY8nJAFTPLPrFNT6mOJxUaj9x6I2IviNeXDBhBBz2Oa5jxT8dLqxE+maVbwG+XKvMPmWE45HPBb/PPSs3xLBYeE9GudVn1TPkL8kIXl27CvGhf3Op6LfagG/eLOLkxBc7QSQTn3449qeBySl7X97HboYxqTS5jTvfEFzrT6g13O1xdrA0omeU787hnP4E1jrI8/h2fy9kSwyRSFk7ZU85PuBVfSLK4m1S7iRCA9tKBuYA/cJHX6VmXseoCxSzNwsds4DGMOMMQTjP619Eqv+zOMo2WwSj+9TTNe31i/OFuIA0gUEgjG5SMg/iCOa3tH8aajc+IfD1peSfZtLsLtJlijHC4/njJ/M1hWMpivBZ3EmVWCN7dwc4QjO3PsTitLQ7CO711Jmb92oOG68c8fXqfwrwfYOM22tj1I1bxVnudn4x1FdH8ZG509mFrqaK0RVztY5IXH/bRSP91xXQaL4hsvE7QaBeSlpDp7XUc5yHDCQqQyk8kLg49jXnviEC7sLfS5VmeXbItrIMAqyHKqPqNo+tZ1z4otofEWi+IrQyrcpbp9pjYfJ5mSGIx65yR6k16tSEpLml1S+8441Ip27MyfFc15oWs3NnqE7CdHxmMYVx2I9qpWGoxXrhPtMm7+67GvW/HeiaFrviywF1M0Ud9bpcQyoBznIK59zj6E+5rmNb+F1nLo326wle0v0LYt5nB3kE4Cn1IGa7YZhVik0lY46lCPM1c525W0tSFnkwxGQDVaSfT3G0lCPeoNM/4mP7+5wzxDy2B9RWsIYgOIkA9gK3eZOWqWhMcN5lBZLQDCyoo9hUitaD/l6X6Vc2oP4VH4U3CkfdX8qX1+RX1ZdyqFtPNEhvAR/dK5Bp4/s/GTMlTHaP4AfwpAUwPkH5Uvrr7D9h5kDXGmJ1nXj0FMW60+VwiTrk+oq0RG3/LNfyqvPYW9whGwK3ZlGKSxf90XsH3Fns0ADqFOOhBqrlCdu+Mn2NZ0VldalqC6Zp7SOSdrBT1NdTc/B2+s4YDLfWi3Nw2yOLecs2M4z06UnmUV8MLkexfcyRCSPQVA2qWdoShdHI6jGf1rOvotR0e6fTL1XRlbYyP1U1Uk0+YOVRC/POBVSr068LJFU3OlLmT1Opt/EOjiFQ9ujN3J4orlhp1yRnYR7GivP+oUvP72eks3r9o/+Ao+topG9SPerUfIzuzW3F4d09jhkY/8CNaFv4Z0tB/qST7sazWJSOH2TObVwOAx/Op4m7Z4rqF0TTEAxbgn3q1FpVioGLaMfWqeLXYSos888SXa2+mvAQWa4GzZ6r3/AA7fjXA3uosD5asBjqB0rY8feJBfalOligSNCY1I9B/jXn95dSRJzkkYJ+nenKpbU+cxMvbVWui0Opsr6WWOBpHDJKzRAZ6FQD/Iir1poNxrt5HbafE00knbHC+pPoK4nQNU+1GGOSVo4FkOMDJO7AYj6hQK+kvDsmk6JoP/ABL0hilkUFTK2Glb3b9fSuWriLIUaDvypHC3vwq0/S2gllka/uP+WkCNhVP8/wA+tdP4qltrD4aL9j8uNZXETKOoLKV2nvkZ/SuS1z4g/wBoarf2UzmwvLF+F5KXUJx8wxnBGc1BqHiybxYmg+FjEBPJeiZzuz90kZ91w2c+1csbyknI66tGVOk9D2Lw3qEF3olwJY032kf2Fsf8tAsakZ/76NeXtr+odVtsf8ANa3w91K51bUpoog32EXDymQniTBAyPb5V/LHrXphs7YLkRoMDP3RW9Kq1ojuy69SneXQ+PfjX4jk1K9stHzGhQebKuMfMeAD+GfzrkTe3GiWsPlEoHlIlXs6qoGD6jlvzqLxRf3fiPxvqd86l55rl9iqOM7sKB+lVdcuoz9ltE+dbT90vGQ7dST7ZJx7V0c1k5bN6I9DT5GhpTJb+KFjZzIrh40dm+8GU4/QiqEzLLFE2z7oKnn3J/rTdNKLfWUm15DvjcnfgZJBq5dpbW8s0AilJjuJF++OnGO3tWvPUnRkr9RJRU4sh1oNJFps0WEcWnykd9rMCPyq3BcS6Peq0chZYvLbOO5Q5/U4pwlgH9jNJahlRZSVZzyA7GqjTbpJ8pDwOM5bHI9frU1aUpPV7xKhNR2XU6bUL439haTqzl4r04CdeVU4H/fNc3qssebaa6idZ3MqTxMMBWBBJH4tnHrXU6YUtNKs5nKKr3Ak+UAbgE6qR3BPIridUZZ/n3s873E8gDHqgC/zwfyrCd7Q5Xqkatq8rrc7m3e88TeCIZMh73QJjEqqcb7dhnA+hHH4V0ul+NtP1DRzqGqQQb9Pi2vNkEmTHy4B5yw54964nwnc/adOfTIiyefD5dwyHlcsDn/vkAd+fpXoukfBLQNZ0wR2+vNCsir5qTuBkrkg5/E1qqyi7Lr+ZnKm5Rv2PFdBGrarqF1HpWny3LSybiEQkJn1Paujl8EeOXOf7MkRfYYrvE+EUHh+8EWiavqkskqhi1hIVVh2yx4/OtuL4aeKHgdm17xJb7RuGLqOYN7YVs/oaIxrJXitCNFpJ6+p5C/g7xtBw2lO31qFtA8Zx4B0dvThc/wBa9ztfhT42uYFns/Gt68TDgs3I9iGGR9DT/wDhVXxIiOU8WzE+4Q/0pfWKy0ugdOPVM8BuLDxTaOUn05kYdf3eagca9H9+2K/9sq+gn+G/xRDAjxIkhH96CI/0preAviqOup6fJ/v2kX+FV9brdxezj2Z8/wAX9sM4BikwfSE1e8q4QFmguC2P+eZFe2SeAvimzA+bozY9bVBUT+CfipESRb+H3+tuv+NTLFVHoyowS2PLfhBaRxeILiHUISss9rI0SuDl/XHfOM16fAlmmn2a26tFLyLZLjO5fl6Y69M8dcVia78L/iVrE1rc/ZNJtbm0YtHLajym+mfSrV34V+K81snnabo8k0HzJcZHmA4xke+KdGtBRtNamU4S5vdPN/iost3rkEbiF9Q+zqJRbg4LZOMd84xWQula7Oo8qymUEdSu3+degaF4Q8T6JdXF5q3hqPVLuZ9xnllYMv0IFdPGbJos33ha9hmzyIp8r+ZxWXtJptxRokmtWeM/8Ifr7/MVAz2MgzRXsDf2Jk50XUgfTzf/AK9FP21XsHLDue0JKP7xFTafIzM6yMcg8HPBFV0bdgEH8quwoQB+7x/wGsTRGjEgIyMfnXN/EfxCPD/h10hfF3d5ijx1A/iP5fzrejT2cfTivHvixeTXfiQ2m5sQIqICfUZP8/0qJysjWnHmkkcJLcGEs3mYycsDyDXP6xqIuGFqiM27/WFew9K0PF2kan4fvIILpQpuYhNGVYNlTkZH5VQ02y2ku5Bc8ms6M5tWvoebmioKekffLFlCNix24HH3UUYrs9Z+IN1p2gW1i2z7ekIWaNiD5bHPB75xgn8BWHJbvpFnYXpRBNes3kbuwHG76ljgfQmsPxRo0VnqYa7tVilaBZHyTyCuSx/zzWrXM7HDh1yr2n3GV/aFzHbyXBmYzocmV+mMDj8j0rqvDN7qNlHc67dI0V3NEbO1H/PNSvzsPfaQPbcPSuR0rTrnxJqUEUMb/Z0fbFHjqxPH1JP1r2H4r6PD4Oh0LTlZS6WA8wjq8hY7m/E/yqKs+WN0bwoyxDdJOy6nrfwstrODwzavHs3tEN2Oo9vp/jXZgRtwRkdCDXkvwH1KS+0qa1dTmHOM9xkV6uYiBzgUUZ80b2PThhVhl7OLueGftB6FYaYNHfSdOtbVxHPgwRBDuO0bjgckDP518w6wksWQ0ckTAnJYYzn0r7B+PWmyS6DYaguGFrcFHx2Vx/iB+dfO3iTSk1CynYKN4TI4qnWlfkexuqSlC63OJ06F5rFJERi6ylePYA1sa1p1xFqV5+6YbmST8xn+orGs43isI5ASVLOTjp0UVsaxcJNIkgTPm2kTE7s8jaD+oNd0KcOSSl2ucrk7q3cZdWc72emsEZeZl5H0J/nUttpTSJLK53J5TBvmCkEFT79s/lVUyrLpAXBLw3QwN3Z1wf1UU/SLxtLu/tRjU27DypUJyMHAyfzP5VEnTsnfoUubmfqdHBctpHh62t5SJo55pWizg7cqFP8Aj+FZngrw/D468YWGmTyyW8N1MI1eNASidOnTtiuo0Xw8001pa3yF40jMkcnZgXboPpWz8LfDkFt4z08Ws2yWO5jIAH3hkHr9AR+NZWcYq3ka25nZlu/+D3iLwNNLHb2TajYgkrcWw3Ej1ZeoP6e9UNKsr251FIN08EbcSkgjaO9fVxZwTxnHqK82+Our3eieF7K/hg3wpfIs4A52srAH88VNGnH2kefa4TqyUHy7nNWNytpb/ZbDy44osKAWOck9+P51q6drDpIP3mT3IOa4PT9esjZNJFsV2iMhVsgkMfXt34qXTNUhKBbaRCoOMKelfawxEGuVbHzc6cr3e57X4c1aIyYbaTKQGbv7ZrqSC3QV4no+vxWs8XmzrGGYINzckk449a9lJnUjJU+vavm8zjBVFKPU9bBSlytSJdrDqBTWBx2qFrmcPtwOelHmXJJ+WMj6mvNO0cyHH/16iYZzwSKVzc8YEYGOetIzsuOAWpgQyoDztqrKAM/LViSRs8qv4CoHY45P6UWAqSp6LmqM0aknKL+Iq/ImRyxqpIRg5zmgkzzbxk/6mP8AIUU9iuTz+lFAFmF8EDBP0q9BcHJzWZED2cflVuE+ufrQCNWOcMAcg/jXh3xBv4bjxhPcR5aIlQD64AGf0rv/AIkeIW8M+Cr++idxOyiGLA5LMcfyyfwr598K6k2oWDm4yWhnIyW3fKeevfkGs60bwua0W1USPRvihpUmq6f4cuYQHlWKRDxngbT2+prjLjS5rWNFmVV3g7HDAqfXDDg12vjfxXY6XYaE0XkEiMyRTu20RSqRxyOh7g9QcVyZ8ZaPF/pUEUMUkr5ntLa8jlgY/wB4JLkEexwR0BI5rPC3jTSPKzrD1JV3Up6pnS2unaXqfhKbWdYskmg0nZbwskrHY2Ccso/hLHr/ALXtXneoyXuuO+oaguI5zjfghcKAAiDsoGPfkV6xo/jfw0mnGIWdr5UhE0sUvloHYfd4Xhsc8CuX8Q/EDQNY1PCaYfkbmXeAqfNk4Udz/QelaxTvax5kIVnHlijb+AvhpdS1hdYFuVs7A7EJT5d2DgA/3hwfbNWvjJLFq3jVgfmSzhSDB6E8sf8A0KvX/A40FvDlp/wj0AisNuVTGGBPXd7mvCvGwnn8daxEASVuWIHoM8fpiprLSzPoMBh1SSieh/Bi38mG6kdQqhcA9O//ANavT96OMg8VyHw205dP0EMy5MhGD7Af4k11wlUAcD2opK0TqrO82ZviPw/a+JdEu9JnyEuI9ocDJRuoP4ECvlrUNMm0u/utMvI9s9u7ROD0JHGR9a+uvOUAZXH414f8dtCjt9VsddhjIW6UwzMo43r90n3I4/4DSqL7Q6MteU+Yb2GTSZmgBKnzJQB/s8Y/lVmzKT2yyyRhzh4wAduABu6fia3fHOhSPs1SFGKqpWTYMkDsfpXNmO4j060RukjSuFCFTggDcT6cH8jXdQlfXdWOarHldttS1am2kS4jMCrsVZOGOchh/iat27LbPLDJbqtvMjRysRuKcEhvwIFZWlxwul5GXMLvbtt3KSCQQewPp1rd0HWWthH51imoQupilQf8tFPBHsR60KXuRly90Fryauei28ep2Wn2B8hnvIbWPbIo3B8MxGO2CKn8JSXPhv4iaTNe2csVg96YzOEJSNW+5luwyfyqFPFY0zTRZNot5HaQxkRzyzru2noq4zuGfQevIrpPCN/NfajY6esohtriZF8lFDockcqTkkdQTx09aEueDbd7W+Ro9JJL/hz6BMbY+VxntWV4l8O23inQL3RtROYrpNu9RyjZyrD3BAP4VqMcZw36Ugb+9k/hXMtBHyV4y0HUfA8ElhrMTJLHgR3SxZS4jBzlXJwc8cdQT0ryoXckt28weQrGD5YJJ5PA/nn8K/QW5tLfUIGt7q2iuITw0cqBlb6g8Vl2fgnwzYTiez8N6Rbyq24SRWcasD7EDitJVZS0uZ+yR4P+z58IdRur+38Ua9bPbWdufMtYZhh5n7Ng8hR156/SvpMxxqSdi57mq72qNlSXUnqVOD+lCQFFAWeUfUg5rNstKxL5ajnbSsgx/gajVXU/fVl9zjFAkXB3Arj1NNDFPAximMpPfApPPt2BxKn/AH10pjTW4zmRfrupiI5Ov3s1WkYDvTpru2/56xf99Cqc13bD5vPgx7sKLMNB0koHOc1RmmT8KSbUbJRhrq2H/AxVCbV9OUc3tsP+Biiz7CbQ55E3HGMUVQOu6YSf9Ptv++qKfK+wro0EjDxldu0twSDg1ZhSS0RQjAqDzu5qvC4wDmrqnIwP1qSkYnxD0d/FvgTUrFB+9QCVVHJJQ7sfiAR+NfOWgnyL64tAu1TECB9D/wDXNfVdgQ0pCgOpXa4zjmvnKTQY9P8AFermRPKSzuHhjTdkck9z1wP5irSThJMcU/aRaNtJZJ9GSNjnYSuG+61czeaDJcMStjpLf70Of1rqIbuxaCTTJZNs0qGSM+hA4b8+PzrmdevrXTtPmurqWaYRjGwHG9ugAA7e9XQiuX0DE6SOL1qF9OuzHtsomXtApA59ear2U/zht7F+2xCf/rVz899Nd3UlwWVC7E4A4X2FSxSu5w95j2LkURkrnM7s92+FPjrUND1IDdN5BGHRxhXH5V0jldd8X6hqcAIS4uiE9SM4/pXl/hS50bTfs0OjudR1GZt09xKqgQIOygkn6mvY/CWuaNqCA3NqEubYi4ypwJgpzx+A6VjXl7R2SO7DQ5Vds9l06zSxsILZBxGgX8e9T7G7AD8aZa3CXttHc27h45F3IR3FTbWzknrStbQzeuozy2OMnNcR8Zod3gWclFJWeI5x935uv9PxruQMdGyKyvE+hp4j0C+0x22/aYiqseiP1U/gQDSaurDi7O58zWyBz5b8qwPXvXGeIY7retyj4spoESBTHuVQOSufb/2auu1Kw1Dwpq6W2q28kNxBKpKk5DA9CD0Iz3rV0rw+kTXFgkjSWUkjFbdjuTqSCM+1XhJ1FJqHzNMQoOKcjy6yt4jpTwXTCD7dOIkuV5CovLZHXGSPyq9pGh6lpjS/agjWkgAR43DKy44Ye1dH4s8EGztBeWkjRpFuhW3eNtqZ5znHuevtWXoEZ/sp40y0mCp9MmujEyhKKpLoc1O6bmx+qk2Olra4jjmA+8OAoPr7n9Px49A+BtnaR6npct9mKdS6QZY87hu3EdOCePzrzm60y8mshak+a2cFjxgenvXoPgWFrCeyEhIaDbh/pgAflRT1jZKzW/mOb1vf/gHul1pviZLh1j1KJ4wflJABI/Kqr6f4qYn/AE6PB9x/hXU20/n2kNxuyHUUMQOM5rP2zWll9wvZp9Tlf7I8UsDnUlB/3v8A61IdD8TkDOrj8zXVtPDHgvKq/wC8wqFr+wTLNdxDH+2OKftpdEvuD2a7nLv4Z12T/W6yfzaon8G6wwBGsZHoWaujl1vT0XcsjyDtsjZv5CqjeLLFGOyC8c+gt2pqrUey/AThEwz4J1ggg6mp/wCBNTW8C6h1Oorn6mtl/F+7mPSL9/8Atliom8T37AtF4fuiP9o4q/aVf6sLlgYb/D65JJbUAGP8S5qIeA71CRLdJIuOCDgmtiXxPrQ6eH5Mf73/ANaqsni3WVXnw/Lg+5P9KOer3/IOWBnnwNDwbi7eLPqP605/h/YlT/pc/wCGKWbxfqU37ttAkbP8JDH+lU7jxNrobdb6NLETxgoxH5YqXKt3C1PsSN4C0/OGnuCfqP8ACqr+B9KT7xmbJ/v4ok8ReKHIP9jbc99p/wDrVSm1HxbJytnGgPOdoH8zS5qj+0DUexM3g3SASPKk/wC+zRWcbvxdk/ux/wB8rRS9/wDmJ07HXwsuByc1a3qsZcqeB2rLhlHA6fjWhA2B93j3Nc5uXtPMTP2Vtowv+FeNfFWzXTPE+oFY8G5jW5QJ/EcYOffKmvYYgm4OY1LDgHHQV5T8fNKa4/sq9tDMLuXfbFF6FByD7EbjzTinsilLldzzvTZ7X/hI5ruV3FrfWoSGQDIR1QDacdOf516h8L/DGl67qOpR6jZwXNibTY8Uq5U7mH6/Kea8w0bwhexMJSYfMZhuLuSc+pOOa95+EmlyafDqYl2NIWiG5TkYwxH86392NNpO7M5c0pXa0PGfir+z1e+FTPrPhlZNQ0cZZ4fvTWo/9mUevUd/WvIBGu8Ky/pX6FLvH+eteYePP2f/AA54vea/00HR9TkJZniX91K3+0nb6rj8amnUS0ZEqb3R80aBPBpcEpgEckshG51OGCj+H867Cx1ouq7UkRjjc/t7V1Pgj9lfWIdTlufEmtQW1sGbbDZHe0voSWACj8CfpWX4n8G3Hg/W5dLlkSQKA8ci/wAaHoSOx46Vy1m+a51UH7vKe3fDDxRZXVgmnxKyMgyA7lifzr0DzDjp+lfKnhvWptFv/NiYh8YAFfTmjSyXulWdzOpSWWJXZT2JFOE29yqsErNF3zMdFIH6UhuCf4SKURgnqwFAXHft3qzE82+Nvh621jRIb54AJYJBG0i4z5bdj7Z/nXnej7LQQ+ShZV4AXv8AjmvoHW9KXWNHurCVVInjKj2OOD+BxXz9Ek9jcujoMxuVeM9QQcGu3CW1VtTGs3ZHZX2hx6hZOzKZAoGI5B0Pv3z2/GvJH0Obwl4gu9LcnAOVJHyuGAZT+Rr2bw9INQtvIU4RuXPel8c+EP7c8EWWpRQ41TTLcLIVHMqIMMPfGMj/AOvWdRck9So+8jyN/Lt2C4Ekp6KP61fsJnhuopWYlgwPB4H0FULW3AG5QCTzmrkYZCNwxjpW8bvczaSPofwxfrqGhwLn548Yx9P/ANVaZh3dHYe4615l4L190uIYx91skj3O1QK9QJQcE9fQ1x1IOLNoyuQy2CyjEgLj3ANUJtCs1cFLG3fJ+bcvNaRc5xkUCZjwSpPtWetiyLy4IECYEQA6dvwqRYIwwdVOfbNG7zFIIDA8EEVEY5Ex5J2rnlDyP/rUtQJjEhJOBz1pPKUE4QflVaHUkldoXBimXqjcZ+nrUrSkdc49PWmIHxjkD2yKiLAHGAPwpXlz3J9qryPk7h1HXnpQASv15HNVJJCMjk09znPQVVlbOeQcd6YMgmJ5qhM/UYPpirEzc5349BWfNJ05z+NAiN5QGPFFV2Y5PJ/OikAQSYOBgmtK2c5OSP51jWspJANaFvKo4yMe9AjXhkJwCPyrhfije29zLYWowZrffI3qmQB+taXivxUNAsNkBzeTZEY6hR/eryi91JyJLiaRpJGOSzNyaT21LijTt9Rt7fZFOCVc4yo6e9eu/D7RZdMsX1CeaVri+RAULfIiIW2kD1IbJP09K8w+HfgubxLfx6vqCvFpkJyqnjzj6D29690TYVxgYHAA44pRuzSbVrFxLnHPGKlWTe2dwx6VRIXA5XPqKUzpGmHdfruxVWZmaDzLGheRsKoLE56CvmbxxrT65r19qBY4d/k9lHAH5CvbfFmsxWXh7UGSVWfyii7T1zx/Wvn26IcSnPbNY1fM1pI6L4U+F/8AhJPEcb3OBawHzHB6vjtX0mjR7RyAAOPavEPhFdW+k29xeXL7N/7uMDv6mu+m8dafGCF8xj7A1pQpTcb2JrTV7XOxWQE/eGKN2RwwyK4KTx8p4iSTnoTgVRk8cXj8Km0dM11LDTfQ53VielbxkfN7V4d44sZtP8XX6743Sd/PA29m5/MHIrck8V37kjcADXn/AIh1ae41a5mAkaYsFLu2QuBjgfStqdKVJ8zIc1PRHa+CrsxXIQgFHOPoa9Zjnt4gbfzVVo0VmUHoGzj+Rr520vUHs0U3ILWsxKO4PMZ/vD6Guos9d1L7Ognl3zBdkjk5L44B9+Kia9tUsik+SOp3fi3wdpHiDS7iG2Sxtb91DRXKqqkMDnBI7Hp+NeJ6nZX2g3EllfblmTGVYhgQehB9K7Ua3ekfLIF+mK5fxXHcX8iXc0x2IArDAzn3pypSprmuEZqbsHhnXxZ6hD5jqq7xyxwB/nNe3aNr9vcWhE0bQvE7RlW43AHhge4I5r5oXAkYgZX3r0fEVnpdhHbnKPHvLKDhicetTH96+Vg/c1PXf7W0/dzOij/eFM/tXTyABdxDv94V479plAwOB2ofVvKBEk6L/wACH5da0+pruT7fyPXpNasUQlboNz/DUY8SWSkD7QvPZjjP514++pg5G+Q/7oJqOTUCTgRyOfUg/wBaPqi7g6/kev3PiHTJYik00DezHn8KzD4ntbMER36soGBuOR/jXlkl3Mx+W2kI9cinLLMy82NwxyOARR9Vj3D2z7Hoc/xGt4GCvb7iW27lbg1Vm+IsSt8tofzzXDzWM+pDDaReKRyDuNLbabfACH+z5x/daVsfgSe9SqdNOzG5y6HXH4jISc2RP41BL8QomziwlIrAk0bVYsf8S9eTxmQf41SuINUjyptIlwcZLf8A16OSl0/MXNI3pvH6E4GnS/XpWZc+P22/LpzA/wC0/wD9asSaHU2PzQQj3qhMl2hO/wAnj/ao5KYOUjabx1dkkiyTB/2jRXN/6X2KgfSilyQ7E3kehQa0gIG1qux6wkh/1T4P0zXJW9jcIQePYntVwwXFvHJO9wVWJCxCgdqw5Y9zZNmB4v1P7brMpQnbEBGMnpgc/rWTpFhJruoraxoXA5bsMVSv7o72Yks7kkn1Jr0Dwd4Xew09LiaZ4Li4Ac7WwQvYVild2ZreyudRaXeu28KQW9pbxRou1QCOnp1q4lx4mkIGbdM44yKz0sgmCb+4LehlNSx/ZgQTdbj7zN/jXWmui/Aws+rL4tPE0gLNe2yk8Ebv/rUn9k6y7HztUhHrjJz+lV0+xL96ZWyef3rf408LpB4PlOD0+dv8afM+34Bb+rmT4u0q60/QbmaW9SYDaMDvzXl0CvPOYgMs5A+vtXpPjqaxj0ZYraGJZJJR9z0xXNeBtIN5rscjqvlQ5kYHoew/U1yV/emdFH3Ym3ZItjZxwLgeWOfc96nWYkZ2jnnp/Wusa1gC58uzHOceWM5o8q1wMzW6j0VAP/1V6UKyilFI5JU23ds5XduY/Jgn7uKt2Njc3gIQRrj+JjgE5rYma1jUl7tFTHOOM/lVK4lswmTdzg9gYjkn2HX9KbxCEqJEdIlyMzwZzjAYnNcr4tsmsrmFmKnzFILAdSD/APqrpBHK7MFeQj/bVlBGetZniawmm01ixd2gO8cccdcHOTxUyqOSsNQszM8PmKexmhcB9r9PUHFaunAR7o7iTZAoxHj5iD/drlfDl8lvq/lSPtjlypb3rtILYRF5Un3IpyQp4Irni7TuaNXjYCbIL8rXDnuVAFZuvSRHSZwlvMm0A7nIPf2rXeZP7qPz2NUdXlT+y7wLA0jLC5CDoTjpXVJNxabMlZM88V+xr0Lw/LHfeH7H7XJKvlGSJSpxlQc/1rz+1eDUJIVt5I9kjBfMLZC59a7LRpPs2nCwE8bGCRyCo5IJHJ/KuSj8RtPY120rTpmLbZHHo2TzUkGlWEJJWEIPUIBVT7ZJF1dj9B1pkl/Iw53kDtmuxxZinE1WSwjTDRkk9jxTfPsAD/o8eR6jNY3mtI248gYGSaOD1Zc59anlvuw5vI2WvIOB5aL64FSxahYRMCYHbvjtWCXTbzn8qYzkcZYjHY0OncaqHXjVbdo2jSDaCD39vrVZ5YWiXjG3gHJz+HNcnJdzIvyk4z61E+oXPI8wisXhrl+1N241uewZdyb4wSPlDYP4Z4NVLrWnnXciIAwznrmsW4upJ4jHKxZGHPNZEs81u4VmLx4wr9x7EUlQS3E6rZvT3LSKwkkjQZORis+b7GMF7ktjsEzVOWcOgfdwfT0qlKyqCCc++KvkSI52aRuLME/vyf8AgIorHLLn7xopciFzM1k8SznHYdKW98TSTWM0ec7xt6dM0UVnOKUWy4ydzC0qNZNTSWVQ8cJD7T3Pau9Pia9mAHlJt9KKKVGKauy5t3GHVLi4B3KqjPrSm8kGAVB4PftRRXTFGbFBlBEm7agBJ5zmiG83qXBDKP4kBGPwNFFEnYErmdq94t2Y1V2dFXI7cn/9VWdAmntrHUfJCfuzE5YnB2kkHnHqRRRXC3ed/M60vcsX4bu7uGLi4AAAyoXI/M8/pV6COYNummLY/hB4I/Kiiu1o50i5DLbWx2lmVehHJqd9VsosYEhOOuOtFFEIpik7bFeTW7Z/mW3ckccmqz6kk52LEBwcqSTxRRWvIkRzNnHSaKLTXIxGSyFvNUE9VzyP6VqR2ssTTSRzNGEQ5Qcgg8YoorncU5M1T0NRtMMsaybyu4BxtYjrz/WoxZYkUfa5gG+Ugc0UVsm2ZtJHmXj3wPNoFw/iHTXUQl8yIcAoxPBx0I/lWn8PfEUkOn/ZrnfdR7xK64AZSc5+bPfr3oorka5amhstYHbzNKNs0UIktpEDxyb8Myn2xxUTzlULtC4APYj/ABoorv6HM1rYrRakjsVWN/xxz+tLJqSRkggoMgA4ziiik9A5SA6zAQdzkYJX7p64pg1W3ckLKxOQCACMUUVCk72HYZJqECuVLk468VWn1KzBG7d9AKKKG9RbFV9Vtn3FEk4HTioHvBNGcQEhhzkgZooqU73GUzJJDzGmFHG3PWoxKJl4JHJHNFFRKTVh2uREDP3qKKKLhY//2Q=="


html: " <img src='data:image/png,base64, " + base64 + "'><br><br>Thank you "
```

however, this doesn't work and the email shows blank!

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var base64 = `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`
html: " <img src='data:image/png;base64," + base64 + "'><br><br>Thank you "
```

Could you try using this instead?

Comment: @Gianluca Anytime